# $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\cdots(2-x^{1/n}))$ convergence domain

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Exercise**: Study the absolute and conditional convergence domain of the following series: $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\cdots(2-x^{1/n}))\quad x>0$$

I have never seen a series like this. I tried to solve it on the following way:

$$\begin{align}\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\cdots(2-x^{1/n}))&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\exp(\ln((2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\cdots(2-x^{1/n})))\\&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}\exp(\ln(2-x)+\ln(2-x^{1/2})+\cdots+\ln(2-x^{1/n})))\\&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}((2-x)+(2-x^{1/2})+\cdots+(2-x^{1/n})\\&=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(2-x^{1/n})\end{align}$$

However $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}(2-x^{1/n})=1\neq 0$ which implies the series do not converge.

**Question:**

1. How do I deal with series like this?
2. Is my resolution right? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: At one point in your analysis you use the identity $e^{a+b}=e^a+e^b$. Seeing _that_ error in an "advanced" context like this is frankly alarming.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich You are right. How could I have not seen it? What a shame! Anyway, any idea about the series convergence domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is a positive power of $2$, it is in fact a finite sum. As noted by David, if $0<x\le 1$, then the series diverges. Let
$$
a_n=(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\dots(2-x^{1/n}).
$$
Fix $x>1$ not a power of $2$. Let's apply the ratio test.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bigl|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Bigr|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|2-x^{1/(n+1)}\bigr|=1.
$$
Since the test is inconclusive, let's try [Rabbet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Observe that $2-x^{1/(n+1)}>0$ for $n$ large enough.
\begin{align}
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1&=\frac{x^{1/(n+1)}-1}{2-x^{1/(n+1)}}\\
&=\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2}).
\end{align}
Then
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}n\Bigl(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\Bigr)=\log x.
$$
The series converges if $x>e$ and diverges if $x<e$.

If $x=e$ then
$$
\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1=\frac{1}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})=\frac{1}{n}+O(n^{-2})
$$
and the series diverges by Gauss's test.

Comment: Cool. I woulda thought that I knew the stuff in a Wikipedia page on the ratio test...

Comment: At the beginning of the argument it is said "Fix $x>1$ not a power of $2$"

Comment: Sorry, missed that.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but after having studied the Raabe's test proof and after reading your answer, a doubt arouse. How did you go from $\frac{x^{1/(n+1)}-1}{2-x^{1/(n+1)}}$ to $\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$x^{1/n}=e^{\tfrac{\log x}{n}}=1+\frac{\log x}{n}+O(n^{-2}).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Since an infinitely superior answer has been given I thought maybe I should delete this. But that answer refers to this answer for one triviality; there's also a point below that's relevant to the other answer. Deleting the parts that are now moot:

Say $a_n=(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\dots(2-x^{1/n})$. If $0<x\le1$ then $a_n\ge1$ for all $n$ so $\sum a_n$ diverges.

For $x>1$ see the other answer. One relevant technicality:

If $x>2$ it's not true that $a_n\ge0$, so strictly speaking Raabe's test cannot be applied. But in that case there exists $N$ so that $2-x^{1/N}\le0$ but $2-x^{1/(N+1)}>0$. Note that $\sum a_n$ converges if an only if $\sum_{n>N}a_n$ converges; for the latter sum start by factoring out the negative factors in each $a_n$ and apply Raabe on what remains.