# Understanding $\frac{x^{1/(n+1)}-1}{2-x^{1/(n+1)}}=\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have been studying another thread about series and Raabe's test, here is the link:[$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(2-x)(2-x^{1/2})\cdots(2-x^{1/n}))$ convergence domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834827/sum-limitsn-1-infty2-x2-x1-2-cdots2-x1-n-convergence-domai)

> $\begin{align}
> \frac{x^{1/(n+1)}-1}{2-x^{1/(n+1)}}
> =\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2}).
> \end{align}$

It has been hard to me to understand the equality above. I am still new to this kind of proof with Landau terminology.

**Question**:

Does it come from the Taylor expansion? How did the author derived it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's treat the numerator separately from the denominator to begin with:

$$
x^{1/(n+1)}=\exp\left(\frac{\log x}{n+1}\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{y^k}{k}=1+y+O(y^2)
$$
where $y=\frac{\log x}{n+1}$. Note that $x$ is constant, so we can write the numerator as $$x^{1/(n+1)}-1=\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O\left(n^{-2}\right).$$

Now we can apply a similar idea to the denominator to get:

$$2-x^{1/(n+1)}=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).$$Now, by geometric series, we have $$\frac{1}{1+O\left(\frac1n\right)}=1+O\left(\frac1n\right).$$Combining these estimates, we get

$$
\frac{x^{1/(n+1)}-1}{2-x^{1/(n+1)}}=\left(\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O\left(n^{-2}\right).
$$

Comment: When you write $2-x^{1/(n+1)}=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, you are referring to the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}2-x^{1/(n+1)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1$? How is the Landau terminology explained on this particular case? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes: I'm using the exact same expansion for $x^{1/(n+1)}$ as in the previous step.

Comment: @ I tried to derive the $O(n^{-2})$ in the first expansion, by repacing $O(y^2)=O(\frac{(\log(x))^2}{(n+1)^2})$. Then I tried to major the expression $\frac{(\log(x))^2}{(n+1)^2}\leqslant \frac{(n^2}{(n+1)^2} \leqslant \frac{(n)^2}{n^2+2n+1}\leqslant \frac{n^2}{n^2+2n}\leqslant \frac{n^2}{n^2}=1$. How did you derive $O(n^{-2})$? Sorry but I am still new to this Landau terminology. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @PedroGomes: $x$ is constant since we're just interested in what happens as $n\to\infty$, so $\log^2 x=O(1)$. This means $\frac{\log^2 x}{(n+1)^2}=O\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)$. Now, $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\leq\frac{1}{4n^2}$ for all $n\geq1$ which means $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}=O\left(n^{-2}\right)$.

Comment: Sorry or bothering again! For the second expression I tried to apply the rational you did apply before: the expansion two terms. But instead of  $2-x^{1/(n+1)}=1+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ I got $1-\frac{\log(x)}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})$. I figured out that you used the expansion with only 2 terms, right? Why? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Pedro: I used two terms just because that was all I needed. If you need more precision, you can, of course, take more terms. It just affects how the geometric series estimate is going to work...

Comment: Sorry again. But How did you multiply with this Landau terminology? $\left(\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O(n^{-2})\right)\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)=\frac{\log x}{n+1}+O\left(n^{-2}\right)$? I apply the standard multiplication rules I get nowhere.

Comment: You just use the standard multiplication rules... FOIL it, as they say.

Comment: How do I deal with $O(\frac{1}{n})\frac{\log x}{n+1}$ and $O(n^-2)O(\frac{1}{n})$? Sorry but I am not into the Landau terminology. Thanks for all your help. This is my last doubt.

Comment: Hi @PedroGomes: Again, $x$ is constant... this means $O\left(\frac1n\right)\cdot\frac{\log x}{n+1}=O\left(\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)=O\left(n^{-2}\right).$ Additionally, $O(n^{-2})\cdot O(n^{-1})=O(n^{-3})=O(n^{-2})$.

Comment: @PedroGomes: I'm not sure of the source of your confusion for the Landau notation, but just remember that it is a "fancy" inequality: since $x$ is constant, this means $\log x\leq C$ for *some* $C>0$. This is all we need for $\log x=O(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^{1/n}=e^{\tfrac{\log x}{n}}=1+\frac{\log x}{n}+O(n^{-2}).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I have already tried something like that: $e^{\log(\frac{x^{1/n+1}-1}{2-x^{1/n+1}})}=e^{\log(x^{1/n+1}-1)}.e^{-\log(2-x^{1/n+1})}$. However I am stuck at this point. What should I do?

Comment: Is this equality $e^{\tfrac{\log x}{n}}=1+\frac{\log x}{n}+O(n^{-2})$, taylor expansion?

Comment: Yes, is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ around $x=0$.$$e^x=1+x+O(x^2).$$ Also, observe that $2-x^{1/(n+1)}\sim1$.